# keep sprite's original size when scaling canvas

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

does anyone know an easy way to keep a sprite's size and position while scaling the canvas size? (zoom in/out). for example, i have a 20x20 bitmap on a canvas, I scaled the canvas to 60%, together with other child comp in it but i want this particular bitmap to retain its size.

Comment: I was about to give a long winded answer, but @MartyWallace is right. I'm guessing you're referring to `<mx:Canvas />`. But even so, my long winded answer would be, well, long winded. It might help if you provide a little more context by showing some code or describing what else is in the canvas, etc. Short winded answer: iterate over the child objects and scale everything but the bitmap, remove the bitmap from the canvas and overlay it on top of the canvas instead, or extend canvas and override `updateDisplayList()` to size/position the child objects manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scale up the bitmap by the same ammount its parent is scaled down - then it will appear to stay at its original size.

If you set scale on 'canvas' to S then you would set scale on bitmap to 1 divided by S.

So if you set canvas scale to 60% - or 0.6, then bitmap scale should be 1/0.6 or 1.66666666...